# How to read from text file to int array, in c++?

Tags: c++, file, text, input, int

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

struct specific {int distance; int arrive_time; int depart_time;};
int maxn=100;
ifstream File("c:\\data.txt");
if (!File.is_open())
{
cout << "Unable to open file!";
exit(-1); 
}
else
{ 
int l;
string rows;
while (getline(File,rows)){
++l;}
int data[l];

if (l>maxn)
{
cout << "Too much data!";
File.close();
exit(-1);
}
else
{
int i=1;
while (!File.eof() && i<=l)
{
Filel >> data[i];
i++;
} 

if (i!=l)
{ 
cout << "Inconsitent File!";
File.close(); 
exit(-1);
}
}
};
Fajl.close();

n = l/3;
specific station[n];
int j=1;
do{
for (int i=; i<=l; i+=3){
data[i] == station[j].distance;
data[i+1] == station[j].arrive_time;
data[i+2] == station[j].depart_time;
j++;}}
while (j<=n);
}
```

I'm totally new in c++, and programming. My goal is - partially, to open a given text file, containing numbers, one number (and nothing else) in each row . I need to read these eventually into the array called station[n]. To do this, I put a int array between the File and the destination (station) array. 
The station array, is a struct, I'm not allowed to change that. The goal is to read the numbers from the text file, into the data array, then put them accordingly from there into the station array.

The trick is that the station array has 3 qualities for each element: station[1] for instance has to have a distance, arrive_time, and depart_time (all positive integers). Which also means that the number of stations will be equal to the number of rows in the text file divided by 3.

I suspect that this can probably be done without the data array, but even so, my code gets stuck at the very beginning: it cannot read the file properly at all. I've read a few articles on this forum as well as others, none helped....
The code above is a partial only, please consider any undeclared element, accordingly declared somewhere in my main code.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please indent your code.  Second: `int data[l];` is not legal C++, as `l` is a variable.  If you're learning C++, turn off the extensions your compiler is giving you and learn the language without them.

Comment: Why do you not format your code?

Answer (score 0):

In 2014 c++ don't be afraid to use the standard library and vectors:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> data;
    std::ifstream DataFile("c:\\data.txt");

    if (DataFile)
    {
        int value;
        // read the elements 
        while (DataFile >> value)
        {
            data.push_back(value);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```